# Should I wrap the whole thing inside <?php ?> using PHP?

Tags: php

Is there any difference between the following 2?

1 separate php code from html

> ```
> <html>
> <body>
>   <?php // php code 1 ... ?>
>   <div> ... </div>
>   <?php // php code 2 ... ?>
>   <div> ... </div>
>   <?php // php code 3 ... ?>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

2 everything inside php

> ```
> <?php
> echo "<html>";
> ehco "<body>";
> // php code 1 ...
> echo "<div> ... </div>";
> // php code 2 ...
> echo "<div> ... </div>";
> // php code 3 ...
> echo "</body>";
> echo "</html>";
> ?>
> ```

Which is faster?

Comment: how about concerning efficiency?

Comment: 1st one, but it cost more time for coding (i guess), there are lots of mvc framework or so, maybe u can take a look on that

Comment: @ajreal: how is this related to MVC? :-S

Comment: @zerkms :- logic and output separation?

Comment: @ajreal: so? is it denied to use <?php and php itself in output? Do you know that there are 2 kinds of logic: business and presentation?

Comment: @ajreal: at least take a look at Zend_View, which contains a lot of <?php ;-)

Comment: if the question owner felt the code he is written getting longer and the existing way of output HTML is getting unreadable for him, a MVC framework might help him to reduce the plain

Comment: @zerkms - asking the owner to take a look on the MVC framework, and maybe can get "inspired" by the concept

Comment: @ajreal: to be clear, he asked about which code is **faster** ;-)

Comment: yup, check the 3rd comment, if the question owner just need a fish, everyone from here is giving him enough fish, but he seems need a fish-rod

Comment: The first one is muuuuuuuch easier to debug ;)

Answer (score 4):

It is not the way to increase the speed. If you are not satisfied with your app performance - take profiler and find the **slowest** part. After that - optimize that **slowest** part.

The way "I optimize the things that it is easy to optimize" is always the worst.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is faster because interpreter will take care only about the code inside the tags.

The second one should not be use, double quotes are interpreted to see if there is a variable inside. You should always use simple quote when you don't want string to be interpreted.

Comment: thanks! My original (naive) thought was that using multiple <?php ?> will invoke the php engine multiple times, thus making it slower.

Comment: The web server receives the HTTP request and determines that the request is for your .php file. It has a handler registered for .php files that says they should be interpreted by the php interpreter. The web server invokes the php interpreter and gives it the .php file as input. The interpreter returns its output to the web server, which may do some more stuff to it, then responds to the original HTTP request. The interpreter was only invoked once regardless of what may be in the file, even if there is no PHP code at all.

Answer (score 1):

The usual usage is what you listed in the first form, although in some cases, such as a helper function to generate `<a href="..." ... >link word</a>`, then you will generate HTML inside PHP code.  Or if you have a function that generates a table, or an `ul` with many `li` printed out with data from inside an array or hash.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever performance difference you'll find is moot and academic. Choose the first form. The second form isn't future-proof. A simple change in the layout of the HTML page will require a software engineer. The first will just require a creative designer.

Answer (score 0):

With an opcode cache installed on the server (see: APC, eAccelerator), it doesn't matter either way, as the page only has to be interpreted the first time it's accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Performance:

Perhaps the 2nd example would be slightly slower because it does more function calls & also when a string is inside double quotes then the interpreter will look for variables to substitute and escape sequences, eg. \n

PHP blocks also need to be parsed. This may be irrelevant is your script is pre-compiled / running on an accelerator.

Formatting:

1st example will produce HTML code automatically formatted with indentation.
The 2nd example will produce code that's all on one line. Not really an issue as this can be corrected.

Readability:

Perhaps the first example is more readable. Eg. IDE can highlight syntax for HTML and separately for PHP

Others:

2nd example would probably be more preferred choice if the code is in a framework and markup gets extracted in to smaller function(s), sub-classed, etc?